# Element not displayed with obj.style.display='';

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a strange issue on a HTML page containing a `span` which won't be displayed:

```
<span id="wipThankYou">Thank you for submitting your email!</span>
```

It is initially hidden with the following CSS:

```
#wipThankYou {
    display: none;
}
```

When a user clicks on a button, the following code is executed:

```
function T_show(obj) {

    if ( obj !== null ) {
        obj.style.display='';
    }

}

var wipThankYou = document.getElementById("wipThankYou");
T_show(wipThankYou);
```

I can see the code being executed step-by-step in Chrome, but the `span` is not displayed. When I inspect the element, its CSS is not changed. I can replicate the issue on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a699x/).

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I took this code from [You Might Not Need JQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), but apparently, it is faulty. Thanks.

Comment: `obj.style.display = 'inline'`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a699x/1/ set it to a value

Comment: I guess this really highlights why you *might need* jQuery after all :) `$("#wipThankYou").toggle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.style.display=''` resets the inline style of the element.  You need to specify how you want to display it if you want it to be shown.  Change it to a display value and it will fix it, such as `obj.style.display='inline-block'`

Answer (score 1):

```
obj.style.display='inline-block';
```

or whatever the display you want (inline, block...), but it shouldn't be empty.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/ELmqf/

Answer (score 1):

`obj.style.display='';` is not valid for css `display` as `display` can be :`inline`(default), `block`, `inline-block` (more values you can find here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

so solution for you to set style to valid value. For example `obj.style.display='block';`

**Live example** http://jsfiddle.net/a699x/2/